# install IIS8 on windows 7?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-8

I am currently looking at upgrading my development environment in an attempt for it to replicate IIS on my production web server. My production web server is new and only recently spun up with windows server 2012 and IIS8.

I am working on a windows 7 machine locally.

Is it possible to install IIS8 on a windows 7 machine?

And if so, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect scenario for a virtual machine.  I would install some flavour of virtualization software and install the version of Windows Server that you are using in production on to it.  This way, when you run IIS8 it will be in an environment that is much closer to your production web server ;-)

Comment: Whilst I agree with the answer, the question itself (is IIS8 available for Windows 7) is still unanswered.

Comment: @DanAtkinson I think VS2012 and 2013 installs IIS 8.0 Express on Windows 7 as well. Not sure if its helpful